# How to access data from an array when it's inside an std object? Error: Illegal string offset 'id'

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

How to access this array object in Laravel 6, using Eloquent?

```
        [line_items] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4088662196333
                        [variant_id] => 29653605285997
```

```
$external = DB::table('orders')->pluck('import_order_data');
...
foreach ($external as $key => $val) {
...
Cart::updateOrCreate([
   'line_item_id' => ['line_item_id' => $val['id']],
],
```

> ErrorException
>   Illegal string offset 'id'

If I change it to:

```
'line_item_id' => ['line_item_id' => $val->id],
```

I get error:

> ErrorException
>   Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

If I change it to:

```
'line_item_id' => ['line_item_id' => $val['line_items']->id],
```

I get error:

> Illegal string offset 'line_items'

EDIT:
The problem was:

```
    protected $casts = [
        'import_order_data' => 'array',
    ];
```

Now I can access it like this:

```
   dd($val['line_items'][0]['id']);
```

Which provides:

```
4092309209197
```

or

```
dd($val['line_items']);
```

which provides:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:26 [▼
    "id" => 4092309209197
    "sku" => "1605"
    "name" => "Printer Ink"
```

Any better options on accessing the data?

EDIT: 
Answer:

```
foreach ($val['line_items'] as $index => $lineItem) {
    dd($lineItem['id']);
```

Which provides:

```
4092309209197
```

Is this a reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your array looks like this:

```
$arr = [
           [
               "id" => 4092309209197,
               "sku" => "1605",
               "name" => "Printer Ink",
                ....etc.....
           ]
];
```

Fine. First, since the outer array only has one item, you can do this:

```
$innerArr = $arr[0];
```

Now you've got this:

```
$innerArr = [
    "id" => 4092309209197,
    "sku" => "1605",
    "name" => "Printer Ink",
    ....etc.....
]
```

And you can access it like this:

```
echo $innerArr["id"];
echo $innerArr["sku"];
....etc....
```

Or like this:

```
foreach($innerArr as $key => $val){
    echo $key.": ".$val."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah pretty much, is this the best way to access arrays inside arrays in Laravel?

Comment: @Josh as far as I know, there aren't any common helper libraries for this in Laravel, but that's mostly because PHP's API pretty much covers what you need.